# Программа по высчитыванию градусов цельсия выдает нули

Tags: java

Почему код выдает постоянно ноль,пол часа уже бьюсь и никак не не могу понять?

```
public class NewMain {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Methods degrees=new Methods();
       double result=degrees.findDegrees(100.4);
        System.out.print(result);
    }

}



public class Methods {

  double degreesC;  
  double degreesF;

  public double findDegrees(double degreesF){

  degreesC=(5/9*(degreesF-32));

return degreesC;

  }

}
```

Comment: Тут бампать надо или это бесполезно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Methods {

    double degreesC;
    double degreesF;

    public double findDegrees(double degreesF){

        degreesC=((degreesF-32)*5/9);

        return degreesC;

    }

}
```

Comment: Работает,спасибо тебе.Но почему?Какая разница где стоит умножение?

Comment: в первом случае 5 и 9 это тип int, таким образом дробной части быть не может, то есть 5/9 = 0, во втором случае double умножается на 5.0 и делится на 9.0, поскольку первый множитель double, то и остальные приводятся к этому же типу

Comment: За меня уже ответили, все верно, дело в приведении типов.

Comment: Можно ещё просто написать 5.0/9 без изменения порядка.